# Is it possible to get Google calendar to send a http call when an event starts?

Tags: http, hook, google-calendar-api

I am integrating Google calendar data with an external app and need to do some operations when an event starts. Is it possible to get Google calendar to send a http call when an event starts?

Comment: Presumably if there was such a feature, it would be well documented in the GCal API documentation. Have you read the documentation? Can you point out a part of the docs that suggest this feature is available?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide). That should be able to let you send a server call or [email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails).